# Query for Splitting a Name Field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a field [Name] which I need to break up into separate parts in a query. The field is in the format:

`LastName,FirstName PossibleMiddle`

Sample values:

```
Doe,John Andrew
Smith,Jane
```

Goal for output:

```
[LastName]          [FirstName]          [MiddleName]
----------------    ----------------     ----------------   
Doe                 John                 Andrew
Smith               Jane
```

Here is the code I've been able to work out until now:

```
SELECT 
LEFT([Name], CHARINDEX(',', [Name]) - 1) AS [Last Name],
SUBSTRING([Name], CHARINDEX(',', [Name]) +1, LEN([Name])) AS [First and Middle Name],
SUBSTRING([Name], CHARINDEX(',', [Name]) +1, (CHARINDEX(' ', [Name])-1)) AS [First Name]
FROM t1
```

This code is not right for a couple of reasons:
1. It fails because the second SUBSTRING is not correctly formulated.  It assumes that there will always be a space, but there will actually only be a space if there is a middle name.
2. I don't want  [First and Middle Name] as one (but I think once the first issue is resolved the rest will fall into place).

I feel like I'm missing something obvious with this but it's been a long morning of trying, searching and no solution yet.  Thanks in advance for taking the time to look and respond.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Newer ones have some new functions that you can potentially use here (STRING_SPLIT in 2016 for example). And you probably won't get a "catch all" function here. What if the person's last name is two words? First name? What if both are two words? What if one has an apostrophe? Or is a Jr?

Comment: @Jacob H: SQL Server version is 2008R2.  I appreciate and understand your concerns.  Unfortunately, this query is not going to fix the fact that the names are being stored in a poorly designed fashion. The goal is simply to extract the respective last/first/middle names, and I can see if we have any anomalies and deal with them.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that SqlZim's answer does handle the two-worded last name problem (I found a case like that in the data).  As long as all parts of the last name are only separated with spaces, that solution will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `cross apply()` so we do not have to repeat a function all over the place for the second part:

```
select 
    lastname   = left(t.str,charindex(',',t.str)-1)
  , firstname  = left(x.val,charindex(' ',x.val+' '))
  , middlename = nullif(right(x.val,len(x.val)-charindex(' ',x.val)),x.val)
from t
  cross apply (
    select val = stuff(t.str,1,charindex(',',t.str),'')
      ) x(val)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TUJNX20615

returns:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| lastname | firstname | middlename |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| Doe      | John      | Andrew     |
| Smith    | Jane      | NULL       |
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

---

To extend your example to include mononymous individuals:

```
create table t (str varchar(32))
insert into t values
 ('Doe,John Andrew')
,('Smith,Jane')
,('Sting') -- mononymous 

select 
    lastname   = left(t.str,charindex(',',t.str+',')-1)
  , firstname  = nullif(left(x.val,charindex(' ',x.val+' ')),t.str)
  , middlename = nullif(right(x.val,len(x.val)-charindex(' ',x.val)),x.val)
from t
  cross apply (
    select val = stuff(t.str,1,charindex(',',t.str),'')
      ) x(val)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WPZXC58652

returns:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| lastname | firstname | middlename |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| Doe      | John      | Andrew     |
| Smith    | Jane      | NULL       |
| Sting    | NULL      | NULL       |
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have this working correctly.  Basically, I used two case statements, based on whether or not there was a space in the name.

So, if there is a space in the name, then break on that for the first name.  If not, take the rest of the field.

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(50)
SET @NAME = 'Smith,Jane' -- 'Smith,Jane Ann'

SELECT LEFT(@NAME, CHARINDEX(',', @NAME) - 1) AS LastName,  
    CASE 
        WHEN (CHARINDEX(' ', @NAME) = 0)
            THEN SUBSTRING(@NAME, CHARINDEX(',', @NAME) + 1, 100) 
        ELSE 
            SUBSTRING(@NAME, CHARINDEX(',', @NAME) + 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @NAME) - CHARINDEX(',', @NAME)) 
    END AS FirstName,
    CASE 
        WHEN (CHARINDEX(' ', @NAME) = 0)
            THEN ''
        ELSE 
            SUBSTRING(@NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', @NAME) + 1, 100) 
    END AS MiddleName
```